# Python basic arithmetic compiler

Tags: python, math-expression-eval, compiler

I am attempting to follow the ["Let's build a compiler"](https://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/tutor2.txt) tutorials, in order to build a basic language compiler for a custom assembly language.

Currently the specs of my compiler are:

> - Accepts a single positive integer of any length as input
> - Accepts two single digit numbers† with a "+" or "-" in between them as input
> - If the program was just an integer, then generate assembly to push it to the stack
> - If the program contained addition or subtraction, then generate assembly to find the sum, and push it to the stack

In the future, I would like to expand the compiler, by adding other operators, logic, variables, and more. So the question is, how can I improve my compiler in such a way, that it will be easier to expand, and add new features to in future?

Here is the code:

```
def runProgram(program):
    if "+" in program:
        index = program.index("+")
        try:
            return "PUSH " + program[index-1] + "\nPUSH " + program[index+1] + "\nADD"
        except:
            #"INVALID DIGITS FOR ADDITION"
            return "FAIL"
    elif "-" in program:
        index = program.index("-")
        try:
            return "PUSH " + program[index-1] + "\nPUSH " + program[index+1] + "\nSUB"
        except:
            #"INVALID DIGITS FOR SUBTRACTION"
            return "FAIL"
    else:
        try:
            int(program)
        except:
            #INVALID PROGRAM NOT INTERGER
            return "FAIL"
        return "PUSH " + program

testPrograms = ["3", "19", "5+2", "5-2", "birds", "12+23"]
for x in testPrograms:
    print(x + ":\n" + runProgram(x))
```

Output in this test:

```
3:
PUSH 3
19:
PUSH 19
5+2:
PUSH 5
PUSH 2
ADD
5-2:
PUSH 5
PUSH 2
SUB
birds:
FAIL
12+23:
PUSH 2
PUSH 2
ADD
Press any key to continue . . .
```

† NOTE: The program will just add the two digits on either side of the operand

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading the 2nd requirement:

> Accepts two single digit numbers† with a "+" or "-" in between them as input

in conjunction with the "12+23" test case. It's a very nice test case, but the double digit numbers are clearly beyond what the spec described. Behavior is unspecified in this case, though your program behaves very sensibly.

In `runProgram()`, the `+` and `-` cases are very similar. Can you break out a helper method that takes `+` / `-` as a parameter?

I recommend phrasing the last portion of the function in this way:

```
else:
    try:
        return 'PUSH ' + int(program)
    except ValueError:
        return 'FAIL'
```

The `in program` aproach seems fragile, especially if you have to handle programs like `5 + -3`. You might want to tokenize early on, and pass in a list like [5, '+', -3]. Or perhaps define functions like `add` & `subtract`, and pass in [5, `add`, -3].